# Why can't I print lambda values into my TSX html components?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Sorry I'm still learning React and Typescript. Why does this print an empty `<h1></h1>` instead of `<h1>Title</h1>` ?

```
<h1>{() => {return "Title"}}</h1>
```

Note: I know I could do  `<h1>{"Title"}</h1>` to achieve the desired result, I want to know why can't I do this with a lambda.

Comment: You are passing in a function expression without ever calling it: `{(() => {return "Title"})()}`

Comment: Hey! That helped me! If you want add it as an answer instead of a comment so I can mark it as the solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing in a function expression without ever calling it, try:

```js
<h1>{(() => {return "Title"})()}</h1>
```